# TokBox OpenTok Alternative?

Tags: api, opentok, videochat, tokbox, video-conferencing

I'd like to offer video chat on my website and was wondering if anyone can recommend an API/service that'll let me do so. I'm familiar with OpenTok, but not happy that it uses Flash. Also, the audio tends to have a lot of noise/feedback - unless you are wearing a headset.

Suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I'm using it for P2P right now, but do want to do group video chat in the future.

Flash is one of my primary concerns. I noticed Flash sometimes crashes when I'm using OpenTok. Though Flash crashes other times, too -- it seems to be more frequent when using it for OpenTok. I understand Flash has its benefits (the big one for me is that I can almost count on my users having it), but I'd like to explore other options if possible. Flash is supposed to be a dying technology?

Audio is the other major concern. There is generally an echo going on and a noticeable delay. Using the same set up (Internet connection, computer, mic/speakers, etc.) and comparing it to Skype, it's obvious that Skype is far more superior.

The player is my final concern. Here are the things I don't like about it:

- I can't remove the top left icon that links to OpenTok. Thus, this isn't something I can truly white label.
- The player comes with volume control, but not video control (e.g. to stop publishing, to stop subscribing). Instead, I am forced to implement my own via the API. Though the API makes it fairly easy to do, I don't think I should have to. Video control should be provided, just like volume control.

Comment: **Full Disclaimer: I work at TokBox. I built the original implementation of OpenTok.**

Could you speak more to your use case? Specifically:Is it one-to-one? What browsers are you targeting? Are there firewall issues to be aware of?

Comment: @monvural - I've updated my post. Looking forward to your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

OpenTok for WebRTC should solve all the issues you've noted above. Find more info here:http://tokbox.com/opentok/docs/concepts/WebRTC.html

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out the API's provided by TenHands (http://www.tenhands.net) to see if this meets your needs. The integration should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please check out how to use Markdown- that way the URL you've provided will be displayed as clickable link.  There's a help icon next to the edit box with a summary of how to use it.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Now there is also EasyRTC ([easyrtc.com](https://easyrtc.com))

Answer (score 1):

To make clear what Gerry said. You can use EasyRTC to build and peer peer video conferencing application. Using easyrtc Lib you can easily make a group chat[video+audio+text+file transfer] within a short time, just see their demo. They already provide a good list of demo application and easyrtc lib is well documented.
Note that, easyrtc does not use flash they use WebRTC. And for video controller you can easily embed HTML5 video controller in the  tag.

Thanks
Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Twilio had a very good progress recently:

https://www.twilio.com/video

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "comparison" list of API providers as defined by VSee:

- http://vsee.com/api

An no .. I don't have any vested interest in VSee.